# Droid 4 no longer finding any GPS satellites

Tags: gps, motorola-droid-4

I have a Motorola Droid 4 with Verizon service. As of two days ago, it is apparently getting no GPS data from satellites. I thought it was a temporary glitch (cloudy sky, just turned the phone on, etc.) but none of my apps that use GPS are getting sufficiently accurate location data and it's clearly relying only on mobile network location.

A Google search for "GPS droid 4" hasn't been terribly helpful. Based on "[How can I fix my Android's crappy GPS?](http://lifehacker.com/5873007/how-can-i-fix-my-androids-crappy-gps)" I checked that I've got GPS turned on (yes), am using AGPS (yes), having the mobile networks help with location as well (yes).

I downloaded [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&hl=en), and I get zero GPS reception even after leaving the phone sitting outside with a relatively clear sky for 30 minutes (far longer than it should ever take to get reasonable satellite fix with any GPS) -- no information at all for the lat/long. Resetting the AGPS and downloading new does not change anything.

I also tried [GPS Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest) and can see zero satellites :\

[image]

Is this a problem that can be fixed (either by me or a professional) or am I looking for a new phone if I want to know where I am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the phone went through a factory reset, the GPS still wasn't working, which supports that the problem is hardware related.

The Droid 4 chip (indeed, all of the circuit board) isn't accessible without significant (read: warranty-breaking) disassembly, and I couldn't find any store that could/would repair.